# Jquery Post response not going to .done method (linkedin oauth)

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to send a POST request using JQuery.

The POST request is to get the access tokens for `linkedin`.

I am getting the json response with 200 status code (checked in debugger tool). The problem I am facing is that after getting the response its not going to the **done** function, its going to the **fail** function.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async:true,
        dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + code +
        '&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+
        '&client_id=' +client_id+
        '&client_secret='+client_secret,

        data: JSON.stringify({
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    code :  code ,
                    redirect_uri : redirect_uri,
                    client_id :  client_id,
                    client_secret :client_secret
                })

    })
        .done(function()  {
    alert("Success.");
}).fail(function()  {
    alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
});
```

Please let me know the issue.